# How to get a callback notification when Http session expired

Tags: python, http, session, bottle, beaker

I am using python bottle with Beaker to manage Http sessions.
So far I know how to set beaker session timeout parameters, and the sessions are cleaned automatically once expired, but I need to do extra DB cleanup when a session expired.

does anyone know how to receive a callback when a beaker session expired? 
Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with beaker, so this is just a wild guess, but can you subclass `beaker.session.Session`?

If so, then your new class could do its cleanup in __del__.

Something along these lines:

```
class MySession(beaker.session.Session):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySession, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def __del__(self):
        # your cleanup here
```

(Or maybe it's [the `expire` method](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/session.html#beaker.session.Session.delete) that you need to define.  Not sure, since I've never used beaker.)